# How to insert array of objects in Firestore?

Tags: java, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[image]I want to insert an array of objects in Firestore? I'm able to add from Firestore console, but doing it from Java it's not working? Here I'm attaching my console snapshot and code is:

```
val map = HashMap<String, Any>()
    map["one"] = request.records
    dayFormDoc.set(map)
```

Here request.records is an array.

Answer (score 3):

try this,

## Android

```
Map<String, Object> docData = new HashMap<>();

docData.put("listExample", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

## java

```
ArrayList<Object> arrayExample = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(arrayExample, 5L, true, "hello");
docData.put("arrayExample", arrayExample);
```

more information https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Hope it's help full.

Comment: I've tried in this way, but I'm getting an error cannot convert tp Firestore Value. As per my observation arraylist with primitive types has no problem @chetan-mahajan

Comment: i will try after change my code. so wait or find another solution. but i'm android developer not full java

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply add an array to a Cloud Firestore database because you'll get an error that looks like this:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Arrays are not supported; use a List instead (found in field array)

So to solve this problem, you should convert your array to a list as in the following lines of code.

**For Android:**

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
String[] array = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
map.put("array", Arrays.asList(array));
dayFormDoc.update(map);
```

**For Kotlin:**

```
val map = HashMap<String, Any>()
val array = arrayOf("One", "Two", "Three")
map["array"] = Arrays.asList(*array)
dayFormDoc.update(map)
```

Comment: No. I'm using List only and my error is "Cannot convert this to Firestore value"

Comment: So that's the problem. You cannot use a List because the List is not a [supported dat type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), you should you `Arrays.asList` as I suggested in my answer. Have you tried it?